# Is there a way to find out what was stored in local char array after using memset(array, 0, array_size)?

Tags: c++, security

I have created that function to handle a secret

```
#define SIZE 100
void secret_handle(void)
{
    char secret[SIZE] = {0}; //initalize the array with zeros
    load_secret(secret, SIZE);
    // some code to manipulate the secret
    memset(secret, 0, SIZE); //clean up after using it
}
```

I thought that I shouldn't worry about the memset function because the array will disappear anyway from the run-time stack when the function **secret_handle** is quit. is there a thing I miss?
Thank you all.

Comment: You won't be able to access it using Standard C++, but it will still be there, on the stack.

Comment: I think this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords

Comment: Without the memset, some unscrupulous code could sniff the stack and see the remnants there.  From a C++ standpoint, doing so is in the undefined behavior zone, but from a debugger or assembler standpoint the stack could be rummaged through.  Depending on platform.

Comment: I'll bet your compilers optimizer will remove that `memset` since, from a C++ standpoint, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Things typically disappear from the stack by adjusting stack pointer, not by performing some sort of stack cleanup. So without (optimization-aware) safe `memset` call `secret` content will most likely be preserved until some other function reuses the stack and overwrites it.

Comment: You can probably force the array to be scrubbed by using `std::fill_n` with the array cast to a `volatile` pointer.